# Why does this function not successfully insert a node into a linked list?

Tags: c, list, pointers, linked-list, stack

The function is supposed to insert a node to a linked list, but it has a bug and inserted nodes do not show up in the linked list. Where is the bug?

```
int insert(struct Node *headList, int payload) {
   struct Node *newNode;
   newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
   assert (newNode != NULL);
   newNode->payload = payload;
   newNode->next = headList;
   headList = newNode;
   return 0;
}
```

I'm pretty sure that `Node *headList` is passed by value, because `headList` does not change outside this function, but I'm not sure how to fix this. Do I need a pointer to a pointer or something?

Comment: return updated `headList` pointer to caller.

Comment: ... or pass the head node by-address (a pointer-to-pointer) and update it by dereference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function modifies the `struct Node` that this pointer points to:

```
int insert(struct Node *headList, int payload) {
    ...
    headList = newNode;
    ...
}
```

however to modify the pointer itself, you need to pass an address of pointer to initialize pointer to pointer:

```
int insert(struct Node **headList, int payload) {
    ...
    *headList = newNode;  // <--  modifies the pointer itself
    ...
}
```

or alternatively you might handle this using the return value since `return 0` seems a bit useless.

Comment: +1 I almost always use this approach rather than the return-value ideology simply because my return value is *never* useless. It, like much of the C library, returns zero on success, non-zero on error. Communicating that back to the call-side is worth going the extra mile to pass the head pointer by address imho.

Comment: @WhozCraig: The problem is his function **always** returns 0

Comment: Agreed. My point was it should not; it should return error/success state *and* employ your head-ptr-by-address method while doing so. A potential error  is not always just a trivial allocation failure. it could be a logic error that aborts the insertion, but using head-pointer-is-return-value ideology completely hides that fact from the caller. Your sample is correct and is *the* way this should be done, and I'd upvote it again if I could.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and appreciate the comments!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any use of `return` statement so instead of going with pointer to pointer, return updated `headList` pointer to caller

```
 struct Node * insert(struct Node *headList, int payload) {
    struct Node *newNode;
    newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    assert(newNode != NULL);
    newNode->payload = payload;
    newNode->next = headList;
    headList = newNode;
    return headList;
}

 //in caller function
  //Some code
  headList = insert(headList,100);
```

If you are very specific about the `return` statement go with pointer to pointer

```
int insert(struct Node **headList, int payload) {
    struct Node *newNode;
    newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    assert (newNode != NULL);
    newNode->payload = payload;
    newNode->next = headList;
   *headList = newNode;
    return 0;
}

//in caller function
//Some code
status = insert(&headList,100);
```

Comment: +1 barring the missing `return` statement in the second sample, it is the way this should be done (checking your `malloc()` of course).

Comment: @WhozCraig: Note that the first call is dangerous.  If the `malloc()` fails, you've just zapped the head of your list with a null pointer, and you can't free the list if that was the only pointer to it.  The second method, with appropriate bug fixes (it doesn't return a value but should; it should check the return from `malloc()` but doesn't) should avoid clobbering the head if the allocation fails.